# Updating dataframe column with values from a different dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I want to update one of the dataframe based on matching id's from the second one, but only on 1 column. Both dataframes contain other columns that I am not concerned about and should not be updated.

For example:

df1

```
id    name  ...
123   city a
456   city b
789   city c
789   city c
456   city b
123   city a
.
.
.
```

so on and so forth

df2

```
id    name  ...
123   City A
456   City B
789   City C
.
.
.
```

So the resulting `df_new` should be:

```
id    name  ...
123   City A
456   City B
789   City C
789   City C
456   City B
123   City A
.
.
.
```

Right now what I'm doing is:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('id')
df1 = df.set_index('id')
df1.update(df2)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

So I tried to write this into a function like this:

```
def replace_names(df1, df2, 'id'):
    df2 = df2.set_index('id')
    df1 = df.set_index('id')
    df1.update(df2)
    df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return df
```

However, this seems to return a dataframe of `NoneType` when used as a function.

I would also like to change this to a method where instead of reindexing two dataframes and resetting them, if there is a way to pick an `id` and `names` column on two dataframes as variables and just apply a function like this only on those two columns, without updating or changing anything else in the rest of the columns on either dataframes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry fixed the question

Comment: update is inplace assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
def replace_names(df1, df2, idxCol = 'id', srcCol = 'name', dstCol = 'name'):
    df1 = df1.set_index(idxCol)
    df1[dstCol].update(df2.set_index(idxCol)[srcCol])
    return df1.reset_index()
```

Parameters:

- *df1* - the DataFrame with column to be updated.
- *df2* - the DataFrame with the source column.
- *idxCol* - name of the "join" column.
- *srcCol* - name of the source column (in *df2*).
- *dstCol* - name of the destination column (in *df1*).

Then call it:

```
df_new = replace_names(df1, df2)
```

Your code failed because:

- In `df1 = df.set_index('id')` you refer to **df** (an external variable,
  despite having both DataFrames specified as parameters).
- In `df1.update(df2)` you update **all** columns, whereas you want to
  update only one column.
- Your function returned **df** - a variable without any connection to
  what this function did so far (maybe it was an empty DataFrame).

Comment: Thanks so much for catching those issues, this is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to extend this if both the dataframes had different names for the column to be updated and/or indexed?

Comment: I corrected my initial solution with different column names (source and target). If you want also different names of the "join" column (*idxCol*), replace the corresponding parameter with 2 new parameters, just the same way.

Answer (score -1):

```
   final= df1.merge(df2, on=['id'],how='inner')
```

then you can drop column that which is not required

Comment: This assumes that the column names on both dataframes are the same. I would like to explicitly put the column names in

Comment: consider using a left/right merge instead of inner since you are only interested in the first dataframe and not the intersection of the two